# Type annotation in Haskell

Tags: haskell, types

This is probably a silly question, and certainly not the best code, but I don't quite understand why if I add some typing information haskell yells at me

This does not work (notice the x:a 3rd line):

```
groupBy3 :: (a -> a -> Bool)-> [a] -> [[a]]
groupBy3 eq = foldr step []
    where step (x:a) res =
            let (used, res2) = foldr insertel (False, []) res
                    where insertel (al) (used, acc) =
                            if used then (True, al:acc)
                            else if eq x (head al) then
                                (True, (x:al):acc)
                            else
                                (False, al:acc)
            in
              if used then
                  res2
              else [x]:res
```

whereas this works (notice the lack of type annotation for x on 3rd line)

```
groupBy3 :: (a -> a -> Bool)-> [a] -> [[a]]
groupBy3 eq = foldr step []
    where step x res =
            let (used, res2) = foldr insertel (False, []) res
                    where insertel (al) (used, acc) =
                            if used then (True, al:acc)
                            else if eq x (head al) then
                                (True, (x:al):acc)
                            else
                                (False, al:acc)
            in
              if used then
                  res2
              else [x]:res
```

Comment: This would be so much easier to read if you used less indentation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`(x:a)` is not typing information, it's a pattern match on the list constructor, putting the head of the list into `x` and the rest into `a`.

Typing information uses `::`, and would be meaningless here anyway because placeholders like `a` from the main function's type aren't visible in the `where` clause; it would be an independent type identifier and thus meaningless.

Answer (score 6):

To add to Sebastian Redl's answer:
You cannot refer to type variables from the top-level definition in the function body in standard Haskell. However, there is a GHC extension called 'Scoped type variables' which allows you to do that (see http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Scoped_type_variables)